# Redirecting to home page

Tags: magento2

We have magento 2.2.6 site running.Recently the site was migrated from one server to another server,we are getting following issue:

when we login into admin and leave that page as it is for some time and refresh the page,it is redirecting to home page Also in the frontend,it is redirecting to home page randomly

Can anyone guide me on this issue

Comment: No  redis or memcache or varnish is setup on the site

Answer (score 0):

This was the issue with cookie domain settings .set the default magento cookie domain settings and it has worked